# Why does octave give different results for 9 ^ 1/2 and 9 ^ 0.5?

Tags: math, octave

Lately I've been trying to brush up on the math I should have learned in high school. (I didn't pay much attention.) Regarding this, college entrance exams and Octave make a great pair.

This morning I got to fractional powers. And Octave had something surprising in store:

```
octave:41> (9 ^ 1/2)
ans =  4.5000
octave:42> (9 ^ .5)
ans =  3
octave:43> (9 ^ 0.5)
ans =  3
```

Maybe I dozed off when we covered this in high school, but no... According to [this website](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/exponent5.htm),

> By the way, some decimal powers can be written as fractional
>   exponents, too. If you are given something like "35.5", recall that
>   5.5 = 11/2, so:
>
> 3 ^ 5.5 = 3 ^ 11/2

So evidently there's some reason why `octave` evaluates these two expressions differently...

Why does Octave evaluate fractional powers differently? Is this a non-feature, or is there a good reason why it should?

Comment: PEMDAS (purplemath.com/modules/orderops.htm) is taught in many schools, and it's what I learned, so it's a bit frustrating that octave does not follow it. Although, I guess in a sense it does follow PEMDAS, it just requires us to ignore the years we have already spent learning to treat fractions as entities in their own right.. hmm... If I were the world's benevolent dictator, there are only two things I would change, and the way mathematics is taught in schools would be one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no Octave expert, but it look like Octave parses "9 ^ 1/2" as "(9^1)/2".  That is, the exponentiation operator has a higher priority (binds tighter) than division. Try parenthesizing like this: "(9 ^ (1/2))".

Comment: Good catch, Bruce. Still, there's a broader trap here. `9 ^ 1/2` is an exact value, and can be reduced losslessly to `3` by any sane CAS. A CAS may treat 0.5 as a floating-point value, however, rather than try to keep an exact representation of it. I tried to get Octave to show this, and failed. I don't know if that means it always uses FP or if it's uncommonly smart about exact representation, or I just didn't find the right corner case. But for example, my HP 49g+ will return a residual if you subtract (9^0.3) from (9^(1/3)), and 0 when you subtract (9^0.5) from (9^(1/2)). Be careful!

Comment: Actually, your broader trap was what I thought the problem was at first.  I had to read the question several times to figure it out.  Without examining Octave in detail, it look like it always uses FP, but that's a total guess.

Comment: Thinko: I meant (9^(0.8))-(9^(4/5)) in my 49g+ example. I was also playing around with (9^0.3333333...)-(9^(1/3)), but it's no surprise that that gives a residual. The surprise is that FP often has roundoff errors with surprisingly short rational numbers like 0.8. FP stores integers exactly; best to assume anything fractional is stored imprecisely.